# Unable To Save Changes To PHP.ini File On Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, linux

I have tried everything I can think of to save the changes (upload_max_filesize) to the php.ini file on amazon linux 2.

I've tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Also tried the ini_set function

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
```

Also tried using .htaccess file

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Nothing seems to save the changes. What I'm I missing?

Comment: There are different ini files for different SAPIs. For CLI, run `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` to see which ini file is used.

Comment: php -i | grep "Configuration File" work! It show that there was a '&' error in the php.ini file and also show what line it was on

Answer (score 0):

**PIECE OF ADVICE**

Check PHP version and open its PHP.ini file. I installed many PHP versions and edited the wrong PHP.ini many times

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

Create a Page called phpinfo.php with the following inside:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Access it to check the Master Values and Local Values. You'll also get the php.ini configuration file location and edit it instead of `ini_set`. When the Master Values are modified, it's applicable to all apps running the same PHP version.